# Access Violation when using SDL2_mixer effects?

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, sdl, 3d-engine

I've been working on my own lib for 3D audio using SDL2_Mixer and DSPFilters by Vinne Falco.
Currently i'm at the stage where i need to create custom DSP to filter audio, while SDL_mixer takes care of the registering of the effects, the actual DSP is proving difficult.

SDL provides:

```
void Effect(int chan, void* stream, int len, void* udata){}
```

From here we have a stream of interleved audio, stream[0L], stream[0R], stream[1L], etc...
I've tried breaking it down into seperate channels:

```
    float *p = (float*)stream;
    int length = len / 2;

    float* audioData[2];
    audioData[0] = new float[length];
    audioData[1] = new float[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (i %2 == 0) 
        {
            audioData[0][i / 2] = p[i];
        }
        else 
        {
            audioData[1][(i - 1) / 2] = p[i];
        }
    }
```

Once split into channels it is processed by the filter successfully.
This is all fine but i now need to recombine this into a stream or how to directly process the stream data. Tried numerous methods but most end in access violations or heap corruptions.

**EDIT1:** Recombine stage:

```
    ///Combine output///
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        p[i*2]=audioData[0][i];
        p[(i*2)+1]=audioData[1][i];
    }
```

Could anyone either point me in **a better direction of processing the stream** or a fix for this excerpt of code?

Comment: You should show your code that you tried for the recombining part that you have the access violation. [mcve]

Comment: You are right, i was able to isolate some parts of the code today so i'm going to delete and repost as a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure len is in bytes, not in float elements. You could use len/sizeof(float). – keltar

This was the answer provided by keltar, which fixes the access violation.
(It was provided on a seperate streamlined question)